# Got Error while Running Mayavi after installing it in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, failed-installation, mayavi

I want to install `mayavi` in ubuntu ,I install it successfully,but when i run `mayavi2` ,it said:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/mayavi2", line 7, in <module>
>     from mayavi.scripts.mayavi2 import main
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/scripts/mayavi2.py",
> line 494, in <module>
>     raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: No module named envisage.ui.workbench.api
> Could not load envisage. You might have a missing dependency.
> ```
>
> Do you have the EnvisageCore and EnvisagePlugins installed?
>
> If you installed Mayavi with easy_install, try 'easy_install
>   '. 'easy_install Mayavi[app]' will also work.
>
> If you performed a source checkout and installed via 'python setup.py
>   develop', be sure to run the same command in the EnvisageCore and
>   EnvisagePlugins folders.
>
> If these packages appear to be installed, check that your numpy and
>   configobj are installed and working. If you need numpy, 'easy_install
>   numpy' will install numpy. Similarly, 'easy_install configobj' will
>   install configobj.

I don't know what to do? help!

Comment: Hi, Mayavi can be tricky to install. Please provide more information: version of Ubuntu, of Python, how did you install mayavi.

Comment: I'm working on  python 2.7.12, the version of Ubuntu is 14.04.2  I first install vtk use"sudo apt-get install python-vtk" .Then use "sudo pip install mayavi".there is no wrong in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 ships mayavi. Use that version unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise and are willing to go a bit further in installation issues.

First you need to remove pip-installed packages from your system path. Else you are at risk of mismatched versions of packages and have little recourse for fixing these problems.

Steps:

1. Remove pip-installed mayavi

   ```
   sudo pip uninstall mayavi
   ```
2. Remove other packages that pip might have installed. For this, it will be useful if you remember or still have the console that has installed mayavi.
3. Install the system-provided mayavi

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mayavi2
   ```

Comment: I checked my input history on the terminal, there is no other pip install after that. Then I run the code as you suggest. First: `sudo pip uninstall mayavi` Second:`sudo apt-get install mayavi2` There is no error. After installed, I checked it with the code `mayavi2`. It gives me that `QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Size mismatch for type 'QUuid' [30]. Previously registered size 16, now registering size 0.Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: I had installed the library of ETS. The code is `sudo apt-get install python-dev libxtst-dev scons python-vtk pyqt4-dev-tools python2.7-wxgtk2.8 python-configobj`<br/>`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`<br/>`mkdir ets`<br/>`cd ets`<br/>`wget github.com/enthought/ets/raw/master/ets.py`<br/>`python ets.py clone`<br/>`sudo python ets.py develop`.Dose the wrong from here?

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I run `dpkg -s mayavi2`, it said `Status: install ok installed`. Then I edit a simply code in the form of .py, `python mayaviTest.py` ,after which, I get the error `ImportError: No module named QtSvg`. This is another problem maybe. Anyway, Thanks again for that you have solved my first question which I post in stackoverflow.

Comment: The single `pip install` command will probably have installed automatically other packages. You can use `pip freeze` to have a list of pip-installed packages. If there are any left that have been installed in `/usr/lib/...` remove them also. Afterwards, run `apt-get update` (to make sure to have the updates). QtSvg is a dependency of qt. So, try reinstalling qt with `apt-get install python-qtpy`. At any rate, make sure that you do not have two versions of mayavi (as the ets one and one from apt-get).

Comment: There are about one hundred pip-installed packages in the list after I run `pip freeze` , while only one named `mayavi==4.4.3`. Also, almost several hundreds files under  `/usr/lib/`, such as `[accountsservice            groff                         libmpi_cxx.so.1.1.3                libvtkGenericFiltering.so.5.10       libvtksys.so.5.10.1                 python3
aisleriot                  grub                          libmpi_mpifh.so.12                 libvtkGenericFiltering.so.5.10.1     libvtkverdict.so.5.10               python3.5]`. Should I remove them all?

Comment: No, you shouldn't remove all

Comment: Have you, in the past, relied much on "pip install" with sudo to install packages?

Comment: Look specifically at "pip uninstall" the following packages: `traits`, `traitsui`, `envisage`, `apptools`, `QtPy`, `vtk` as they might need an update. But do not remove packages installed by apt-get.

Comment: From the history of terminal (of course as I remeber, too)     `1710  pip install mayavi
 1711  sudo apt-get VTK
 1712  pip install VTK
 1713  sudo pip install mayavi
 1714  sudo pip install vtk
 1715  sudo pip install vtk6.2.0
 1716  apt-get install python-vtk`    I tried to use `pip install` with sudo to install vtk, but obviously failed. And there is nothing more, expect packages that I installed before I wanted to install mayavi2.

Comment: stop using "sudo pip install". use "pip install --user". Also, libraries like vtk, python-vtk, and python-qtpy are best installed with apt-get. The continued mix of apt-get installs with pip installs in `/usr/lib` makes your issues impossible to diagnose. There is an overview of the problem at http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html